# How do you update the text of tkinter buttons for use in a chess game?

Tags: python, tkinter, chess

I'm writing a simple chess game using tkinter. The aim was to move the Pieces (objects) by clicking the starting and end square (selecting the coordinates of the piece to move, and the coordinates of the destination). However I don't seem to be able to update the text of the buttons to show that the pieces have moved. I have looked at a number of previous answers/solutions however most require each button to be changed/selected individually which I can't do as the board(visual representation) is a bank of 8 by 8 buttons.

Most recommend using tkinters StringVar() however I can't seem to get it to work.

I suppose my question is how could I update the buttons after a move is made.

```
['WR', 'WN', 'WB', 'WK', 'WQ', 'WB', 'WN', 'WR'] row 1
['WP', 'WP', 'WP', 'WP', 'WP', 'WP', 'WP', 'WP']
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
['BP', 'BP', 'BP', 'BP', 'BP', 'BP', 'BP', 'BP']
['BR', 'BN', 'BB', 'BK', 'BQ', 'BB', 'BN', 'BR'] row 7
```

Board_visual is set up in game as a 2d list to look like this (above):

```
import game
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
first=True

main=Tk()
main.title("TEST")
main.geometry("1000x1000")
buttonframe=Frame(main)
buttonframe.grid(row=0,column=0)
index=0
colour="white"
for i in game.board_visual:
    index2=0
    for j in i:
        if j==None:
            j=""
        buttontext=StringVar()
        buttontext.set(j)
        Button(buttonframe, textvariable=buttontext,fg="red",command=lambda row=index,column=index2: move(row,column),font=30, width=10,height=2,bg=colour,).grid(row=index, column=index2, sticky=W)
        if colour=="white":
            colour="black"
        elif colour=="black":
            colour="white"
        index2=index2+1
    if colour=="white":
        colour="black"
    elif colour=="black":
        colour="white"
    index=index+1

def move(row,column):
    global first
    if first==True:
        first=False
        global startx
        global starty
        startx=row
        starty=column
    else:
        endx=row
        endy=column
        first=True
        game.board[startx][starty].move(endx,endy)
        game.update(game.board,game.board_visual)

        update()
def update():
    index=0
    for i in game.board_visual:
        index2=0
        for j in i:
            buttontext.set(j)
            index2=index2+1
    index=index+1
main.mainloop()
```

The use of global startx and starty allow me to store the co-ordinates of the first button pressed out side of the main loop. I have done this so that when the second button is pressed I have both sets of co-ordinates for the move function.

I'm still new to python and programming in general so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I really appreciate any help you could give me. Also this is my first time posting a question so I've read through the advice, so I hope I'm in the right place. If there is an issue with this question please tell me and I'll try to correct it. Should I cut out some of the unrelated code? e.g the bit that causes the colour of the buttons to alternate from white to black.

Comment: The short answer is, yes this is possible. You would most likely need to use a 3D array of buttons with self referential calls and then check their `text` value on the other side to determine the action needed. But this to me sounds like a misuse of the tkinter library which isn't really designed for this sort of thing and there are more suited Python libraries out there for the purpose of game design, such as [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news). You would likely have a much, **much** easier time using an alternative library.

Comment: Thanks, I won't says this was the answer I was hoping for but I'm not surprised. I'll look into pygame. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

One solution I have found is to make a function to change a button and call it after every move. This works; however, I believe that it creates new buttons rather than changing the existing ones, which is probably a bad solution. I'll post the code here in case someone finds it helpful.

```
def button_text_change():
    index=0
    colour="white"
    for i in game.board_visual:
        index2=0
        for j in i:
            if j==None:
                j=""
            buttontext=StringVar()
            buttontext.set(j)
            Button(buttonframe, textvariable=buttontext,fg="red",command=lambda row=index,column=index2: move(row,column),font=30, width=10,height=2,bg=colour,).grid(row=index, column=index2, sticky=W)
            if colour=="white":
                colour="black"
            elif colour=="black":
                colour="white"
            index2=index2+1
        if colour=="white":
            colour="black"
        elif colour=="black":
            colour="white"
        index=index+1
```